# Node JS Mail request

Tags: node.js

I want to make my node js server listen to requests from email.

for example:

```
I send to nodejs@gmail.com a mail with an image from myemail@gmail.com.

The node js server will know about it and upload the image.

After that, the node js server will be sent to myemail@gmail.com that it succeeded or failed
```

I already tried to search on google but I was found nothing.

Comment: ok so what is your progress on code ?

Comment: i have an object that contains image and data like first name,last name and so on... i want that a client can send this object by mail and post it in the database